# C# dll resource files changing languages

Tags: c#, .net, dll

We have C# dll project and in the solution and references for that dll project I have Resources project. That project contains two files for our strings such as Labels.resx and Labels.ES-MX.resx. In my C# code to use strings I simply add using MyProject.Resources at the top and reference strings like Labels.myStringKey.

To change the language I have this code:

```
this.cLanguage = language;

            // Setting different culture
            CultureInfo culture;
            culture = GetCultureInfo(language);

            if (culture != null)
            {
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
            }
```

I pass 'Spanish' as my language and I can see that this code returns {es} as a culture. However, our .ES-MX. strings are not being used (I can see that I'm still reading from Labels.resx and not from the Labels.ES-MX.resx file).

So, my question is - what do I need to change in order to use correct resx files and to properly switch language to Spanish?

Comment: You're specifying Spanish, but your resource file is Spanish - Mexico. Spanish is spoken in over a dozen countries, so perhaps specifying Spanish is not enough? If you're not localizing for specific countries, then name your resource file `Labels.es.resx` instead. [ASP.net is not using other locale resource files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520287/asp-net-is-not-using-other-locale-resource-files)

Comment: Hi Dan,

The same ES-MX file is used in our Web application fine. I want to understand if my code to switch languages is correct and if it is, perhaps I can somehow tell it to use ES-MX when the language is Spanish (es culture)?

Comment: I see no obvious issues with the code, but you'll have to try it out. I can't predict what issues you'll experience in your environment.

Comment: I did try it out and I see that my es-mx file is not being used. What's why I'm asking this question as what should I do to make sure my es-mx file is read when the culture is {es}.

Comment: `es` and `es-mx` are two different cultures. If you want to use your `es-mx` resources then you need to set the culture to `es-mx`, and not simply `es`.

Comment: Yes, will be trying this code now:
switch (language)
                {
                    case "Spanish":
                        culture = new CultureInfo("es-mx");
                        break;
                    
                    default:
                        culture = GetCultureInfo(language);
                        break;
                }        
Just tried and it worked. Perhaps you want to move your answer as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying Spanish as the culture, but your resource file is Spanish (Mexico).

`es` and `es-mx` are two different cultures. If you want to use your `es-mx` resources then you need to set the culture to `es-mx`, and not simply `es`.

```
culture = new CultureInfo("ex-ms");
```

See [ASP.net is not using other locale resource files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520287/asp-net-is-not-using-other-locale-resource-files)
 for more details on this.